# Metaprogram and Metametaprogram with BLOOP

Tags: computational-mathematics

I'm solving one question and have a problem. Problem is this:

Imagine $f(x)$ in the following way. We give an input $x$  to a BLOOP program $Π$ , which prints out another BLOOP program $Π_x$. Then run $Π_x$ (no input) which produces $f(x)$.

I need to prove that class of function $f$ which can be computed this way is larger than the primitive recursive functions.

However, I do not know how to approach this problem. I do not think class of function is no more than primitive recursive function now on. Do you have any idea?